# crear un repaorte de impresión configurable personalizado (factura) en asp mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, mvc, controller

miren, tengo un reporte que llamemos general, donde cada usuario crea su reporte personalizado, entonces, en una hoja de tamaño normal, funciona bien, pero cuando el tamaño de papel cambia se daña todo, alguien puede asistirme a ver que falta?

ASi es como envio la informacion a la pantalla del reporte personalizable
    @model Domain.POS.Sale

```
<h2>Detalle de Factura</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            @if (Model.SalesDetails.Count == 0)
            {
                <h2>No existen Detalles registrados aun :'(</h2>
            }
            else
            {
                <div id="DivIdToPrint">
                    DETALLE DE FACTURA
                    <table id="myTable" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Producto
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Cantidad
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Precio
                                </th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.SalesDetails.Where(p => p.SalesId == Model.SalesId))
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Name)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.SellPrice)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            }
        </div>

    </div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            //$('table').DataTable({
            //    "order": []
            //    // Your other options here...
            //});

            $('#BtnPrint').click(function() {
                var divToPrint=document.getElementById('DivIdToPrint');
                var detalle = "";
                 detalle += " No. Factura......: <b>" + '@Model.SalesInvoiceNo' + "</b>   </br>  ";
                detalle += " Cliente..........: <b>" + '@Model.Remarks' + "</b>   </br>  ";

                detalle += divToPrint.innerHTML;

                detalle += "<hr>  ";

                detalle += "<table width='100%'>";

                detalle += "<tr>";
                detalle += "<td width='50%'> Monto Adeudado &nbsp&nbsp:";
                detalle += "</td> ";
                detalle += "<td width='50%' align='right'>  <b>" + '@Model.DebtAmount' + "</b>  ";
                detalle += "</td>";
                detalle += "</tr>";

                detalle += "</table>";

                  var url =  '@Url.Action("DetailsPrint", "Reports", new {area = "Configurations", id = @Model.User.AuthorId, description = "Factura"})';

                  url = url + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(detalle);

                  var win = window.open(url);

                if (win) {
                    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
                    win.focus();
                } else {
                    //Browser has blocked it
                    alert(
                        "Porfavor, debes permitir que se abran las ventanas emergentes o el reporte no va a salir :'( ");
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Este es el reporte que recibe lo que sea que se le envia con jquery

```
@model Domain.GEN.Report



<style type="text/css" media="print">
    .buttons {
        display: none;
    }

    p {
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        -ms-word-break: break-all;
        word-break: break-all;
        word-break: normal;
        -ms-hyphens: auto;
        -moz-hyphens: auto;
        -webkit-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
    }

    .label {
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    #page {
        size: auto; /* auto is the initial value */
        margin: 0; /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
    }
</style>
<body>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportId)

    <input type="button" id="btnImprimir" name="btnImprimir" tabindex="1" value="Imprimir" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-4 btn btn-primary" />
    <input type="button" id="btnCerrar" name="btnCerrar" tabindex="2" value="Cerrar" class="col-sm-2 btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 0.5em;" />
    <div id="Div2" style="position: relative;width: @Model.Width; height: @Model.Heigh;">
        @*<div id="Div2" style="position: relative;width: '@Model.Width'; height: '@Model.Heigh';">*@
        <div>
            <table id="TableHeader" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman;  font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="4" style="width: 15%">

                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Imagen))
                        {
                            <img src="@Url.Content(Model.Imagen)" alt="Image" style="width: auto; height: 107px;" dir="rtl" />
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="4" style="width: 75%; text-align: center">
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Header1))
                        {
                            <div>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Header1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                        }
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Header2))
                        {
                            <div>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Header2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                        }
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Header3))
                        {
                            <div>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Header3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="4" style="width: 0"></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center">
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(@ViewBag.MyDescription))
                        {
                            <div>
                                @ViewBag.MyDescription
                            </div>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div>
            <table id="TableBody" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman; ">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(@ViewBag.MyBody))
                        {
                            <div>
                                @Html.Raw(ViewBag.MyBody)
                            </div>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="position:absolute; bottom: 0; text-align: center">
            @*<div style="position:relative; text-align: center">*@
            @*<div style="text-align:center ">*@
            <table id="TableFooter" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Footer1))
                        {
                        <div>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Footer1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </div>
                        }
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Footer2))
                        {
                        <div>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Footer2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </div>
                        }
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Footer3))
                        {
                        <div>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Footer3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </div>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            document.querySelector("#btnImprimir").style.display = "none";
            document.querySelector("#btnCerrar").style.display = "none";
            window.print();
        }
        // window.close();
    </script>
</body>
```